# Can i Dual install Ros Lunar and Kinect?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

can i dual install those ? If i can't is there a clean way to purge Lunar?

Can i kept my catkin workspace?

i am happy for all help and answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271595/can-i-dual-install-ros-lunar-and-kinect-?/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- create another account
- chroot
- docker

---

Originally posted by [play4fun](https://answers.ros.org/users/32035/play4fun/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0